# generate all mst's with igraph in r

Tags: r, igraph, minimum-spanning-tree

Given that for a graph the Minimum Spanning Tree might not be unique I want to generate all distinct MSTs with igraph in R. Is that possible?

For now, I'm obtaining a single MST:

```
completeGraph <- graph.adjacency(distanceMatrix, mode='undirected', weighted = TRUE)
mstGraph <- mst(completeGraph,algorithm = 'prim')
```

Comment: The minimum spanning tree of a _weioghted_ graph is almost always unique, as different weights will eliminate any degeneracy. If you are looking for all spanning trees of an unweighted graph, add your vote [here](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/1827). Keep in mind that there are an extremely large number of spanning trees, see Kirchhoff's theorem. Thus this is not generally a useful thing to do for network analysis. igraph does have `sample_spanning_tree()` to uniformly sample all spanning trees using loop-erased random walks.

Comment: If after this you still believe that you need all _minimum_ spanning trees of a _weighted_ graph, then you can open a feature request at https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues. Make sure that you describe a convincing use case and provide references to algorithms that solve this problem. When you open the feature request, there will be a template to add al this information.

Comment: better provide an example for `distanceMatrix` with your quesiton.

Comment: @Szabolcs tks for the quick reply. I'm aware of the points you raised. I'm indeed concerned with MSTs and the fact that they're not unique. The almost always you menrtoned is based on the fact that there are no ties in edge weights, which, in my case, is not the case :-) My distance matrix has lots of ties and for me it would be helpful to obtain all distinct MSTs. I will try to open the issue, but I'm not aware of an algorithm for solving it...

Comment: @Dr.No If you can take some time to research potential algorithms, that would move this issue forward. In these cases, searching and reading the literature if often as time consuming as implementing the algorithm. Contributions in this area are also welcome.